# How do I send this dynamic form in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress loop and I have built a dynamic form from it, how would I now grab all the form data and send it?

```
$items = array();                       
$queryBasket = "SELECT * FROM baskets";
$gotBasket = $connect->query($queryBasket);
while ($basket = $gotBasket->fetch_assoc()) {
    //echo $basket['item'];
    $items[] = $basket['item'];
}

$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('product' ),
    'order'     => 'ASC',
    'orderby'   => 'title',
    'post__in'  => $items
);

$loop = new WP_Query($args);

$i = 0;
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul id="basket" class="row">';
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) { 

            $loop->the_post();

            $i++;
        ?>
            <li class="col-sm-12">
                <a href="<?php echo bloginfo('url'); ?>/my-quotes/?del=<?php echo the_id(); ?>">x </a>
                <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>" class="item-name"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                Quantity: <input type="number" name="item-<?php echo $i; ?>-count" id="item-<?php echo $i; ?>-count" class="item-count"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="item-<?php echo $i; ?>-name" id="item-<?php echo $i; ?>-name" value="<?php the_title(); ?>">
        <?php }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {

}
wp_reset_postdata();    
?>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: deleted the first question and asked again...? if you don't echo your HTML-content but rather store it in an variable, you then can both echo the variable and send it in an email...

Answer (score 0):

make it an array:

```
name="item[<?php echo $i; ?>][name]"
```

you can then iterate over it

```
foreach ($_POST['item'] as $i => $values) {
  echo "Name for $i: " . $values['name'];.
}
```